# Extruding the camera block for my phone model

Tags: modeling, extrude

I want to do in my 3D model a bulging camera block. Of course, I know this can be done using the "extrude" tool. But I can't use subdivide modifier, consequently I can't do that. And I want to do a "notches" (It's Google Translate, not me) for power button (like power button in Moto Inc. Smartphones)
[image]

> So, I hope you understand me, because I'm not good in english. Please, don't throw tomatoes at me :) And remember, I don't want to steal someone's design of smartphone, I'm just learning to do something like this.

This is my .blend file:

[image]

Comment: I can't understand your question: why you think extrusion is not possible because you can't (?) use a subdivision modifier? If you wish your mesh to have those details, you must subdivide and extrude some part of it. Otherwise you can also model buttons and cameras as independent meshs and then just join them to the phone body: depending on your model usage, it could also work...

Comment: @m.ardito Yes, I can also model buttons and cameras as independent meshs, but that's not that i want. First of all I don't know why, but I can't subdivide backside of my model. And even if I use subdivide modifier, I will get unsimetric grid, but I need a symetric grid.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide the model (eg: through blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), so to see why you can't subdivide (you don't need the modifier here, you should edit the subdivision manually only on those areas, imho)?

Comment: @m.ardito watch thread.

Comment: You aren't using [Subdivision Surface modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html) in your gif.. You subdivide in Edit mode which are different things. You can't subdivide in Edit mode because Ngons which are present there won't be subdivided (if you toggle in Vertex mode you'll see that they get subdivided with vertices but not splitted with edges). Subsurf will subdivide them but it's better to avoid them altogether if you want to subdivide your model in an expected way.

Comment: @MrZak when I use subdivision surface modifier, I got this: (http://i.imgur.com/B4zThaB.png)

Comment: @Arsen Saruhanyan imho your model has bad topology to do what you wish, thus you may need to modify/rebuild its mesh topology before to be able later to get desired subdivisions. We can help with your specific model, but for that we need you to share it, try this service: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (above comment missed hyperlink)

Comment: @m.ardito done. Watch thread.

Comment: Why do you want extrude it instead of using separate meshes? There is no advantage in that, regarding good topology or vertex count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an edit of your object with a more detailed topology (ngons at minimum, and you can easily replace them with quads, preferably, if you need to subdivide those faces).

It is not finished and it has a n X mirror modifier, but you can see that the "camera block" is quite easy to do now, and (after applying the X mirror, maybe) also side buttons, with a regular manual subdivision with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

[image]

Here is the .blend file. Hth.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do is is to create the part (camera for example), delete the face(s) where the part will be inserted and then fill in the missing faces between part and the rest of your mesh.

It makes it easier if you make the outer edge of the camera have the same number of vertices as the outer edge of the back-face. 
[image]

Select the back-face part of your mesh and open the **Delete menu** and choose the option **Only Faces**
[image]

If the outer edge of the camera has the same number of vertices as the outer edge of the back-face then you can use the **Bridge Edge Loops** option from the **Specials menu** to fill in the missing faces.
If not then you will have to fill in the faces by hand.
[image]

[image]