# Phone camera in Blender 2.79

Tags: modeling

[image: Here is where I am at:]I need some help on how to make a camera separately for a phone model step by step. Like for example: a Samsung galaxy s8 camera.

And also just one more question: How do you put a phone screen image on the phone model? I just started blender.

Comment: What specific part of the process you need help with?

Comment: The camera part like u know the lens.

Comment: How do you make the edges of the camera round? I tried that after extruding it but it makes squares only.

Comment: Please add some images and a detailed description of where you are getting stuck

Comment: I updated the question. So basically I seen some videos on making a phone model and I wanted to start doing it to get better at 3D modeling. So I got some of the major 3D modeling done. I have the phone camera, screen, and the color theme left.

Comment: @Helpasker Hello and welcome, you should ask only one question per post, so people can focus on addressing a single problem, make as many posts as necessary. Also try to focus on a specific part of the workflow you have difficulties with, so your question isn't too broad or doesn't require a full tutorial to answer

Comment: Also make sure you search before posting, these questions have often been answered before https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70089/extruding-the-camera-block-for-my-phone-model https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139912/how-to-add-extra-loop-cuts-without-affecting-subsurf

Comment: Thank u! I'll try to be as simple as possible.